# What are main difrences between * ^ and & in visual-C++ 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010, pointers, c++-cli

What are main difrences between `*` `^` and `&` in visual-C++ 2010?

Comment: Any reason this would be VS-specific? The meaning(s) of all these symbols is defined in the standard.

Comment: Manly I ment for .net  C++ apps. 2Carl Norum: bouth, please explain what is difference between Unary and binary.

Comment: Retagged C++/CLI as this is really about the various "pointer-like" constructs in the language with the extensions for .NET.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tracking reference in C++/CLI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380315/tracking-reference-in-c-cli)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

^ was introduced in C++/CLI for managed objects reference, replacing the * sign used for native object pointers. So, having two types, managed and native, you need to write:

```
class Native
{
};

ref class Managed
{
};

Native* pn = new Native();
Managed^ pm = gcnew Managed();
```

& may be used to get native pointer from the native class instance. It is not used by the same way for managed classes, which are accessed only using reference.

```
Native n;
Native* pn = &n;
```

Comment: `%` is used in managed code to get a tracking handle to a managed variable declared using stack based semantics, much like `&` takes the address of a stack variable in native code.

Answer (score 2):

You mean C++/CLI, the new "managed C++" designed by Microsoft.

- `Type*` still declares a native pointer
- `Type^` declares a reference to an object allocated with **gcnew** (you can think of it as a "pointer on managed objects")
- `Type&` still declares a native reference

Comment: `Type^` is not a reference but a tracking handle.  `Type%` is a tracking (gc-aware) reference to a managed type.