# How to return a string from a function in C++/CLI?

Tags: string, c++-cli

I try the following

```
String ^displayEmail(void){return (^Registration_List[0]);};
```

The VC++ 2010 compiler shows the following:

```
Error   1   error C3192: syntax error : '^' is not a prefix operator (did you mean '*'?)    c:\users\marco\desktop\cs351\hw3\project3\CRegistration.h   43  1   Project3
Error   2   error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'System::String' to 'System::String ^'  c:\users\marco\desktop\cs351\hw3\project3\CRegistration.h   43  1   Project3
```

Comment: Try simply removing the ^s. From what I can see they're the managed equivalent of * (pointers), which you probably don't want to be returning anyways.

Comment: Having the C++ tag on this question is just messing a lot of people up and going to cause you to get a lot of inaccurate answers. It needs to be clear that this is C++/CLI.

Comment: What is the type of Registration_List? The first ^ seems ok but the second one is not ok.

Comment: I'll admit I haven't used C++/CLI, but would it still not be returning the equivalent of a pointer? Anyways, as the compiler indicates, the `^Registration_List[0]` doesn't work. From Jesse's link, I think what you might be looking for is `%Registration_List[0]`, as the `%` is the managed address-of operator.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks. I should only tag cli

Answer (score 0):

> What is the type of Registration_List?
>   *The first ^ seems ok but the second one is not ok.*
>   –  akhisp Mar 9 '12 at 3:03

Answer (score -1):

bazaar.  ^ is the bitwise XOR operator
You can't use it in a definition

Comment: It has additional meanings in Microsoft's C++-CLI.

Comment: Seems like there called [tracking references](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380315/tracking-reference-in-c-cli).