# Modifying objects from another class by passing them into a class constructor

Tags: .net, pointers, reference, constructor, c++-cli

I want to pass object to another class in order to modify it and i want changes that i make to it to be propagated to this object in class instance from which it was taken. This should be working with this code:

```
public class sth{
private:
Object^ thisObject;
public: sth(Object^ ob)
{
    this->thisObject=ob;
}
void someFunct()
{
   this->thisObject=gcnew Object();
}
};
```

but it doesn't work. On the other hand this code:

```
public: sth(Object^& ob)
{
    ob=gcnew Object();
}
```

works fine but if i want this handle to be used by some method that is not invoked by a class constructor i have to create a global handle which i thought (since c++/cli handle is an pointer to reference) would be possible in this way:

```
public class sth{
private:
Object^ thisObject;
public: sth(Object^% ob)
{
    this->thisObject=ob;//this doesn't works
    /*ob = this->thisObject;*///this neither
}
void someFunct()
{
   this->thisObject=gcnew Object();
}
};
```

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380315/tracking-reference-in-c-cli)

and i think i understand the way pointers and references works in c++/cli, do i?

How to accomplish this without creating global variable in parent class and passing its instance to a constructor?

Code from parent class:

```
void method()
{
    array<Object^>^ thisArr=nullptr;
    verifyDial^ thisDial = gcnew verifyDial(thisArr);
    thisDial->ShowDialog();
    if(thisArr !=nullptr)
       //do sth
    else
        return;
}
```

and here is the verfiyDial class:

```
public ref class verifyDial{

public: array<Object^>^ thisArr;
public: verifyDial(array<Object^>^ arr)
{
      this->thisArr=arr;
}

///////////////////////
void someMethod()////event handler
{
if(/*everything went right*/)
{
this->thisArr=gcnew array<Object^>(2);
this->thisArr[0] = true;
this->thisArr[1] = true;
}
this->Close();
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure, you do have a good reason to use C++/CLI, right?

Comment: I don't think you can pass an object constructor with ref.    Could you use a method and pass the object by ref?

Comment: @svick Application i write is pretty much done so i guess i have.

Comment: 1. Your code doesn't compile, do you mean `public ref class sth`? 2. How exactly does the code not work if you say it doesn't work? Does it cause a compile-time error? Exception? Something else? 3. It's not clear to me what exactly are you trying to do. Could you post an example of how do you intend to use this code?

Comment: @Blam Not really. Modyfing operation is invoked by an event handler so it cannot be done manually

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to do, but generally you need to understand what is actually passed to the method (by reference or value).
When you define (and call) a method that has simple type parameter it is generally passed by value (unless you specifically define the method to get variables address/reference). With complex objects/classes the address/reference to the object is passed by value, but but because it is a value of the reference/address it does NOT matter unless you want to destroy (or recreate completely) the actual object. You can still reset ALL object's members/attributes using the value of the reference to the object.

Just to clarify your intentions: are you trying to create utility class to hold "default" values for various other classes?

For me

```
  Class1 c1 = new Class1();
```

is cleaner and more understandable than

```
  Class1 c1 = ...;
  someUtilityClass.resetClassReference(c1);
```

Comment: Speaking about code is kind a higher English level for me, so please keep in mind that i could misunderstood you. I dont want to create utility class, although it would solve my problem. What percisely i want to do is to call a method which will create object array nullpointer and then create an instance of some class that would took this array reference (or pointer) and then by creating global variable make this array able to be modify by this invoked class methods. Once this class is disposed the parrent class would check if array pointer still points to null and choose further operation

Comment: Reading through all your posts I am guessing this is what you want:
class someUtilityClass {
public: someUtilityClass (anyOtherClassRef ref) {
this.ref = ref;
}
public: doWhateverYouWantWithAnyOtherClassRefPassedToConstructor () {
...
}
}

In order to do anything like that you will need to pass reference of the reference to someUtilityClass constructor. And even than it will depend on the sequence of how it is called:
Class1 c1 = ...;
someUtilityClass(&&c1);
someUtilityClass.doWhateverYouWantWithAnyOtherClassRefPassedToConstructor();
will work

Comment: Continued from above:
but 
Class1 c1 = ...; 
someUtilityClass(&&c1);
c1 = ...; // Do something with the object
someUtilityClass.doWhateverYouWantWithAnyOtherClassRefPassedToConstructor();
will NOT work